# Show AVS/CVN status on Magento

Tags: checkout, sales, authorize.net

I've been researching endlessly for the past week or so... but is there any way to show AVS/CVN status from Authorize.net to Magento? I know on PayPal, it does show if there's a match/mismatch/denied status.. but not for authorize.net.

I looked in the database and there is a row called cc_avs_status in sales_flat_order_payment -- but it's null and blank. Magento HAS to store this data somewhere, right?

Anyone know how to implement this on Magento? Specifically on the Sales > Customer Order page?

Answer (score 5):

**AVS Response**:

I've used 3 Authorize.net payment modules with Magento:

- Core
- IDP_AuthorizeCim
- Gorilla_AuthorizenetCim

**None of these store the AVS response** - the only place they are available is via the gateway response object.

Now, there is some information stored from the transaction and if you were to coax the Authorize.net payment gateway module into storing AVS response my guess is to save it to `additional_information` field and not the column `cc_avs_status`; it seems to me that only Paypal Direct saves to that field (my personal experience, have not done deep investigation).

If you were to implement gateway response storage yourself, you'd have to manually set the AVS response into the `setAdditionalInformation` method.

**CVN**:

[CVN](https://support.cybersource.com/cybskb/index?page=content&id=C421&actp=LIST) (also called [CVV](http://www.cvvnumber.com/) or [CCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code)) is *never* stored.

The payment card industry (PCI) have prohibited that these types of numbers not be stored:

> As a security measure, merchants who require the CVV2 for "card not
>   present" payment card transactions are required by the card issuer not
>   to store the CVV2 once the individual transaction is authorized and
>   completed.[4] This way, if a database of transactions is compromised,
>   the CVV2 is not included, and the stolen card numbers are less useful.

And:

> The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) also
>   prohibits the storage of CSC (and other sensitive authorisation data)
>   post transaction authorisation. This applies globally to anyone who
>   stores, processes or transmits card holder data.

<sub>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code</sub>

Comment: He's wanting to know the CVV match response codes I'm thinking. Usually when someone asks about AVS/CVV in the same sentence, they're wanting the AVS match returns and the CVV match returns, not the CVV code itself.